# How do I make dynamic Clarity context menus (dropdowns) under Angular work?

Tags: javascript, angular, vmware-clarity, clarity

I'm attempting to generate a context menu on the fly using the Clarity UI library under Angular.  I couldn't find a 'contextmenu' Clarity component, so I'm using the `dropdown` component - I realize that dropdowns are supposed to work by being attached to a button, but I don't want it attached to a button - I want it as a right click menu, as discussed below.  (Sorry for the length of this post, I just wanted to make sure all the info is there.)

I have a Stackblitz with the problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xsp8ik

In my main component, I have two SVG circles, which, when I click on them, I want to make a dynamically generated context menu appear (for this example, I just have left mouse click, in my real code, I have JointJS nodes that respond to a right click).

The main component creates the 'contextMenuInfo' structure that holds the mouse location information (to specify where the menu should appear), a boolean indicating that the menu should be shown, and a node id, indicating which circle was clicked.

```
<div (mousemove)="onMouseMoved($event)">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" (click)="itemClick(1)" />
    <circle cx="75" cy="25" r="20" (click)="itemClick(2)" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute" [style.top]="contextMenuInfo.top" [style.left]="contextMenuInfo.left">
    <contextmenu [showContextMenu]="contextMenuInfo.showContextMenu" [nodeId]="contextMenuInfo.nodeId"></contextmenu>
</div>
```

The contextmenu component contains the html that should display the context menu.  There are three types of elements in the clr-dropdown-menu: a `label` which creates a menu header, an `item` which should produce an actual menu button with a callback to click, and a `submenu` which should produce a nested sub-menu.  The code uses `*ngFor` to loop through the menu items, and the `*ngIf` statement to test which type the item is, and will display the appropriate thing.

```
<clr-dropdown class="contextdropdown" [clrCloseMenuOnItemClick]="true">
    <clr-dropdown-menu *clrIfOpen="showContextMenu" class="contextmenudropdown">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItems()">
            <label *ngIf="item.type === 'header'" class="dropdown-header">{{item.text}} for node {{item.id}}</label>
            <button *ngIf="item.type === 'item'" type="button" clrDropdownItem
                (click)="item.click(item.text)">{{item.text}} for node {{item.id}}</button>
            <clr-dropdown *ngIf="item.type === 'submenu'">
                <button clrDropdownTrigger>{{item.text}}</button>
                <clr-dropdown-menu class="contextmenudropdown">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let subitem of submenuItems(item.id, item.text)">
                        <label *ngIf="subitem.type === 'header'" class="dropdown-header">{{subitem.text}} for node
                            {{subitem.id}}</label>
                        <button *ngIf="subitem.type === 'item'" type="button" clrDropdownItem
                            (click)="subitem.click(subitem.text)">{{subitem.text}} for node {{subitem.id}}</button>
                    </ng-container>
                </clr-dropdown-menu>
            </clr-dropdown>
        </ng-container>
    </clr-dropdown-menu>
</clr-dropdown>
```

Here is the code that generates the contents of the menus.  It arbitrarily creates submenus every 5 menu items.

```
  menuItems() {
    const list = [];
    list.push(
      { type: 'header', text: 'Heading', id: this.nodeId }
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      if (i % 5 === 4) {
        list.push(
          { type: 'submenu', text: 'Submenu' + i, id: this.nodeId }
        );
      } else {
        list.push(
          { type: 'item', text: 'MenuItem ' + i, id: this.nodeId, click: this.callback }
        );
      }
    }
    console.log('created menuItems list of size: ' + list.length);
    return list;
  }

  submenuItems(nodeId: number, submenuId: number) {
    const list = [];
    list.push(
      { type: 'header', text: 'Submenu Heading for ' +  submenuId, id: nodeId }
    );
    for (let si = 0; si < 5; ++si) {
      list.push(
        { type: 'item', text: 'SubMenuItem ' + si, id: nodeId, click: this.callback }
      );
    }
    console.log('created submenuItems list nodeId: ' + nodeId + ', submenuId: ' + submenuId + ' of size: ' + list.length);
    return list;
  }

  callback(id: string){
    console.log('item ' + id + ' clicked');
  }
```

These are the problems I see:

1. Using the showContextMenu boolean in the main component is not good since it will not get reset when the menu is closed after a click, which means that every second 'click' on the circle gets absorbed - I'm not sure what the correct way to do this is.
2. For this stackblitz, the context menu doesn't actually get displayed. It looks like it gets triggered to get displayed because putting a breakpoint in the menuItems() and submenuItems() routines shows that they get called, but nothing is actually shown.  My actual code seems to show the main menu ok - sorry, but I cannot figure out why the stackblitz doesn't show the menu, and my actual code does.  Once a solution is provided for this, then the remainder of the questions below will likely need to be answered.

Here is a picture of the menu displayed in my actual prototype application:

[image: Picture of main menu displayed in actual application]

3. I don't know why, but the menuItems() routine gets called twice for each click on the circle.  In my actual code, I actually see that once the menu is displayed, the menuItems() routine gets called many many times, especially when moving the mouse on and off the context menu itself (the menu stays displayed - just move the mouse on and off).  Is there a way to limit the number of times this is called?  The final application may take significant time to populate the menu, and I don't want it to be called so frequently.
4. When the menu is shown (in my actual code), clicking on any menu `item` does seem to trigger the callback as desired, however the entire context menu does not disappear (which it should, because `clrCloseMenuOnItemClick` is set to true).
5. Clicking on a `submenu` button does not make the defined `submenu` appear - it does nothing.

Thanks, I appreciate any help you can provide.